# Login com níveis de permissão

Tags: php, mysql, login, permissões

Tenho um sistema de login que, caso o usuário seja um administrador, será redirecionado para uma página e caso seja comum, para outra.

Essa coluna `ativo` é o que define se um usuário é admin(1) ou não(0).

```
identifiant  |  senha  |  ativo 
aaaaaaaaaaaa    12345       1
bbbbbbbbbbbb    12345       0
```

A página de login:

```
<!--A parte do formulário-->
<?php session_start(); ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="
    margin-top: 14px;">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Login</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body" style="background: rgba(32, 40, 76, 0.59);">
                        <?php 
                        if(isset($erro)) 
                            if(count($erro) > 0){ ?>
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <?php foreach($erro as $msg) echo "$msg <br>"; ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php 
                            }
                            ?>
                        <form method="post" action="validacao.php" role="form">
                            <fieldset style="background: #9498a9;">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input  class="form-control" placeholder="Identifiant" name="identifiant">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" required placeholder="Senha" name="senha" type="password" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Lembrar-me
                                    </label>
                                </div>

                                <button type="submit" name="login" value="true" class="btn btn-success btn-block" style="background: #232b4f; border-color: #e2e2e2;">Login</button>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                        <p class="text-center text-danger">
                                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['loginErro'])){
                                        echo $_SESSION['loginErro'];
                                        unset($_SESSION['loginErro']);
                                }?>
                        </p>
                        <p class="text-center text-success">
                                <?php 
                                if(isset($_SESSION['logindeslogado'])){
                                        echo $_SESSION['logindeslogado'];
                                        unset($_SESSION['logindeslogado']);
                                }
                                ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

A página de validação:

```
<?php
    session_start();    
    //Incluindo a conexão com banco de dados
    include_once("conexao.php");    
    //O campo usuário e senha preenchido entra no if para validar
    if((isset($_POST['identifiant'])) && (isset($_POST['senha']))){
        $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['identifiant']); //Escapar de caracteres especiais, como aspas, prevenindo SQL injection
        $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['senha']);

        //Buscar na tabela usuario o usuário que corresponde com os dados digitado no formulário
        $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE identifiant = '$identifiant' and senha = '$senha' LIMIT 1";
        $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
        $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);

        //Encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
        if(isset($resultado)){
            $_SESSION['id'] = $resultado['id'];
            $_SESSION['ativo'] = $resultado['ativo'];
            $_SESSION['identifiant'] = $resultado['identifiant'];
                if($_SESSION['ativo'] == "1"){
                    header("Location: principal.php");
                }elseif($_SESSION['ativo'] == "0"){
                    header("Location: principalUSU.php");
                }
        //Não foi encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
        //redireciona o usuario para a página de login
        }else{  
            //Váriavel global recebendo a mensagem de erro
            $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha Inválido";
            header("Location: login.php");
        }
    //O campo usuário e senha não preenchido entra no else e redireciona o usuário para a página de login
    }else{
        $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha inválido";
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
?>
```

**O grande problema é que mesmo digitando login e senha certos, diz que login ou senha são inválidos e redireciona pra página de login**.

*OBS: Essa pergunta se parece com uma que perguntei, mas o código é outro, preferi não editar aquela pergunta porque aqui o código ta estruturado de uma maneira diferente e eu não queria perder o código anterior.*

Comment: Você esta misturando "MYSQLI API" com "MYSQL API". Isso vai dar problema. Na outra pergunta o código apesar de usar ambas APIs elas estão em arquivos diferentes e lá provavelmente funciona, o código aqui já não tem como funcionar, recomendo que se mantenha na outra que ao menos não é um "erro de digitação".

Answer (score 3):

login.php

```
        <?php
                session_start();
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="pt-br">
          <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="author" content="Cesar Szpak">
            <link rel="icon" href="imagens/favicon.ico">

            <title>Login</title>

            <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
            <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

            <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
            <link href="css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

            <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
            <link href="css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">

            <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
            <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
            <script src="js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

            <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
              <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
              <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->
          </head>

          <body>

            <div class="container">

              <form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="valida.php">
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Área Restrita</h2>
                <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
                <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Senha</label>
                <input type="password" name="senha" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" required>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block" type="submit">Acessar</button>
              </form>
                  <p class="text-center text-danger">
                                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['loginErro'])){
                                        echo $_SESSION['loginErro'];
                                        unset($_SESSION['loginErro']);
                                }?>
                        </p>
                        <p class="text-center text-success">
                                <?php 
                                if(isset($_SESSION['logindeslogado'])){
                                        echo $_SESSION['logindeslogado'];
                                        unset($_SESSION['logindeslogado']);
                                }
                                ?>
                        </p>
            </div> <!-- /container -->


            <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
            <script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
          </body>
        </html>
```

valida.php

```
    <?php
            session_start();    
            //Incluindo a conexão com banco de dados
            include_once("conexao.php");    
            //O campo usuário e senha preenchido entra no if para validar
            if((isset($_POST['email'])) && (isset($_POST['senha']))){
                    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']); //Escapar de caracteres especiais, como aspas, prevenindo SQL injection
                    $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['senha']);
                    $senha = md5($senha);

                    //Buscar na tabela usuario o usuário que corresponde com os dados digitado no formulário
                    $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$usuario' and senha = '$senha' LIMIT 1";
                    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
                    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);

                    //Encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
                    if(isset($resultado)){
                            $_SESSION['usuarioId'] = $resultado['id'];
                            $_SESSION['usuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome'];
                            $_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] = $resultado['niveis_acesso_id'];
                            $_SESSION['usuarioEmail'] = $resultado['email'];
                            if($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "1"){
                                    header("Location: administrativo.php");
                            }elseif($_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] == "2"){
                                    header("Location: colaborador.php");
                            }else{
                                    header("Location: cliente.php");
                            }
                    //Não foi encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
                    //redireciona o usuario para a página de login
                    }else{  
                            //Váriavel global recebendo a mensagem de erro
                            $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha Inválido";
                            header("Location: index.php");
                    }
            //O campo usuário e senha não preenchido entra no else e redireciona o usuário para a página de login
            }else{
                    $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuário ou senha inválido";
                    header("Location: index.php");
            }
    ?>
```

sair.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    unset(
        $_SESSION['usuarioId'],
        $_SESSION['usuarioNome'],
        $_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'],
        $_SESSION['usuarioEmail'],
        $_SESSION['usuarioSenha']
    );

    $_SESSION['logindeslogado'] = "Deslogado com sucesso";
    //redirecionar o usuario para a página de login
    header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66219/discussion-between-victor-and-mariana-ferreira).